# pass image with textField to another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, segue

I have two view controller class on first i have a image view plus textField inside the imageView and on second view controller there is a imageView. First view controller have a done-button, on clicking done-button i want imageView with textField pass to the secondViewController imageView.
Is there any way to do it?
Please suggest me.

Comment: you can use quardzcore frame work to create layers and capture the imageview and textfield in one uiimage and pass that image to the second view. currently i am away from my mac so i cant post any code for that :)

Comment: ok; please because i can't understand that; or if you know any tutorial

Comment: You need to explain more what you're trying to accomplish. You don't  generally pass image views or text fields to another controller. Do you want to pass the image that's in that image view, and any text in the text field? Does the image view in the second view controller also have a text field as a subview?

Comment: yes; i need to pass the imageView on the firstViewController which contain textField; after that pass the image with the text interred to secondViewController with the same image and text

Comment: sorry :) wait for some time will give you some code snippets :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UIImage *)renderImageFromView:(UIView *)view withRect:(CGRect)frame
{
    // Create a new context the size of the frame
    CGSize targetImageSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width,frame.size.height);
    // Check for retina image rendering option
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetImageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetImageSize);
    CGContextRef context2 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // The view to be rendered
    [[view layer] renderInContext:context2];
    // Get the rendered image
    UIImage *original_image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return original_image;
}
```

Try this function for Render image

And the below one for merge them

```
- (UIImage *)mergeImage:(UIImage *)img

{
    CGSize offScreenSize = CGSizeMake(206, 432);
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(offScreenSize, NO, 0);
    else UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(offScreenSize);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 206, 432);
    [imgView.image drawInRect:rect];
    [img drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage* imagez = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return imagez;
}
```

You can change coordinates and height,width according to your requirement.

Comment: if there's any tutorial for more explanation

Comment: please tell me how this methods on class A right; how i can call these methods on class B. i have error for the imgView.image it's mean my imageView?

Comment: you don't need to call it on class B you need to call the method on the Done button click in class A

Answer (score 0):

Example:

This method is declared in ClassB.h

```
- (void) setProperties:(UIImage *)myImage MyLabel:(UILabel *)myLabel;
```

This above is implemented in ClassB.m

```
- (void) setProperties:(UIImage *)myImage MyLabel:(UILabel *)myLabel
{
   //assign myImage and myLabel here
}
```

Then in ClassA

```
ClassB *classB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
[classB setProperties:myImage MyLabel:myLabel];
```

Comment: please i'm new developer can you explain to me how to assign the image and label; or if you know a suitable tutorial

Comment: i put now the image and the textField on subView inside the first viewController; so i can pass this view which included the image and text to the secondViewController